# Name that pattern: Does a decent name for this type of executable module already exist?

Tags: design-patterns, main-method

I'm having trouble naming a set of software modules that follow the same pattern. I'm hoping this already is a named pattern as I can't come up with a decent name.

The situation:
I have a fairly sophisticated/complex object oriented application, complete with unit tests. I need to start running the thing and playing with it. There are maybe 5-10 entry points into the code base that might make for good executables, but I'd rather not commit to any in particular and build command-line parsers, config file parsers, etc, at least not yet. Before I do, I'm building a set of main methods where all the program parameters are hard coded. These are much easier to modify than true executables and I'm the only one who needs to see them during this playing around stage.

What would you call these source code modules that are just a set of hard coded parameters, followed by a call to the main controller class? I don't want to call them 'executables', as that's what I'll build next - the things with config files, command line parsers, user inputs, etc. I don't want to call them 'scripts' because they are in my main application language (plus I reserve 'scripts' for my ruby/python/bash scripts that do quick and dirty stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

How about *driver*? **Note**. Not a device driver or anything like that. That's what I would be inclined to call it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd call that sort of thing a "stub executable".

Answer (score 0):

Update from OP:

After spending some time with a thesaurus, I'm calling the package these executables live in 'vignette'. A vignette is a short, complete scene in a play or movie.

The executables themselves I'm giving verb-names. So "RunAnalysis", "DisplayVisualization", "ImportDataFromFile", etc.